# ZeroKnowledge Proofs in Plutus?

Tags: plutus

From what I heard Plutus / Smart Contracts will bring also the possibility to do Zero Knowledge Proofs.
But I struggled to find further Details in the Documentation.

So here are my Questions:

Anyone knows where to find more detailed documentation on **how / if** ZK Proofs will be implemented in Plutus.

**If** ZK Proofs will be implemented into Plutus are they limited to the domain of ada / token transactions or can they be considered as some sort of ZK Framework to proof other Datasets from other Domains as well (i.e. age)?

Comment: Some info can be found in this document: https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/soniczero-knowledge-snarks-from-linear-size-universal-and-updateable-structured-reference-strings/

Some bits in this video with Markulf Kohlweiss about Zk-SNARK https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAJERtcZamc

And in this video of Charles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M67Z1d-sUug

However looking at it from the perspective of someone trying to apply it to real world problems it all still seems to be in the research phase?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Plutus makes it possible to validate zero knowledge proofs as it is a Turing-complete language. However, verifying zero knowledge proofs can be very complex, and go over the execution budget. To allow for a more efficient execution of zero knowledge proofs, the IOG team is working in introducing built-in functions of the most expensive operation required when verifying pairing-based zk-proofs, pairings. These type of proofs have the most efficient verifiers. You can find more information on the use cases of pairings in the draft CIP (note that this is a draft as it stands).

https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/220

There is a bunch of different possible ZK proofs, and implementing a ZK verifier does not necessarily bound the statements that one can verify. IOG is involved in an open source effort of the implementation of Plonk, one such proving system.

https://github.com/ZK-Garage/plonk

However, there are no concrete plans on when this will be used to verify statements on chain.